# Берется стандартный DocumentRoot вместо VirtualHost (Apache CentOs)

Tags: centos, apache2

Мне нужно настроить 2 сайта.Но для обоих сайтов корневую дерикторию ставит из DocumentRoot /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf.В httpd.conf нет VirtualHost. в hosts домены тоже добавил.Рестарт делал. Каждый конфиг для сайта сделал отдельным .conf файлом. в них прописано:

> example1.com.conf

`<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example1.com
    <Directory /var/www/example1.com>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        Options FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`

> example2.com.conf

`<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example2.com
    <Directory /var/www/example2.com>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        Options FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`

> /usr/sbin/httpd -S видит эти конфиги.
>
> httpd.conf не изменял - он стандартный

Comment: Обнаружил прикол, если удалить virtualhosts, и перезапустить апач, все равно кидает на стандартный каталог сайты, даже переходя по этим доменам

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, в вопросе выдачу `/usr/sbin/httpd -S`. И как вы, собственно, пытаетесь вызвать сайты?

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем, не желаю ни кому сталкиваться с такими необъяснимыми вещами. Не объяснимы конечно они в силу своей опытности. Но вопрос удалось решить путем установления другого сайта на другой порт.

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:8081
Listen 127.0.0.1:8080

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
   ServerName lalala.c
   DocumentRoot /var/www/lalala.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8081>
   ServerName topolya.com
   DocumentRoot
```

/var/www/topolya.com

Дети хлопают в ладоши. Всем спасибо

Comment: Ваше решение - это уход от решения